# Sound device stop working PJSUA - underflow error

Tags: c, pjsip

I'm using pjsip 2.3 on Linux and I get some problems. The system work fine multiples days. But after a random time, there are no more sound from soundcard :

1. All the calls are handles/hangups normally
2. Sound from files is working
3. RTP is correctly send/receive

The log message indicate always this message :

> Master/sound  Underflow, buf_cnt=276, will generate 1 frame

According to this reference : https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/audio-check-sound-device-jitter

> The PortAudio? audio abstraction in PJMEDIA prints the number of
>   underflow/overflow when the sound device is closed. With pjsua, you
>   need to set the log level to 5 (--app-log-level 5), and when the
>   application exits the underflow/overflow statistic will be printed to
>   console/log.

Apparently the sound device is closed, but I have no callback on_sdn_dev_operation.

How can I handle or avoid this state. Are they any callback ?

There is my config media :

```
//pjsua_media_config.ec_tail_len
pjsua_media_config configMedia;
pjsua_media_config_default(&configMedia);
configMedia.snd_play_latency = 100;
configMedia.snd_rec_latency = 100;
configMedia.max_media_ports = 100;
configMedia.snd_auto_close_time = -1;
configMedia.ec_tail_len = 0;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Master/sound Underflow` log is not generated when closing the sound device. The log you will see when the sound device is closed will look something like this: `pa_dev.c Closing <some device>: n underflow, n overflow`.

The `Master/sound Underflow` log is printed when there are not enough samples in the delay buffer to fill a frame. I've also experienced these logs in connection with lost sound.

Comment: But why there are no call on_snd_device_closing ?